# Not able to run a .net3.5 based exe on a pc having VS2010/.net4?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have a .net3.5 based exe which when I run on a pc gives the following message :"unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application."????

The pc has winxp sp3 and vs2010 installed on it so .net4 based apps are running but .net3.5 based exes are not.According to me if the pc has .net3.5 then it should be able to run .net3.5 based apps????

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot run applications targeting .NET 3.5 on a computer that does not have .NET 3.5 installed.

.NET 4.0 is not backwards-compatible with .NET 3.5. It uses a different version of the CLR. So your conclusion is incorrect: you must install *both* versions of the .NET Framework if you want to run applications targeting both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.

However, .NET 3.5 uses the same version of the CLR as .NET 3.0 and .NET 2.0. So if you want to run apps that target any of those frameworks, you can do it by installing .NET 3.5.

The download link for .NET 4.0 explains that:

> The .NET Framework 4 works side by side with older Framework versions. Applications that are based on earlier versions of the Framework will continue to run on the version targeted by default.

However, if you've written the application yourself, and you wish it to run on the new CLR included with .NET 4.0, you can do that by modifying the [`<supportedRuntime>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) in the application's configuration file. Simply add the string "v4.0".

---

I hope that answers your question. But what you say is still somewhat puzzling to me:

> According to me if the pc has .net3.5 then it should be able to run .net3.5 based apps????

I assume that this is a typo, and you meant to say that if a PC has .NET 4.0, then it should be able to run .NET 3.5-based apps. If that's the case, I already addressed that above, in explaining that .NET 4.0 is not backwards-compatible with apps that target an earlier version of the CLR.

If it's not a typo, it seems inconsistent with the rest of the question. You seem to be implying that .NET 3.5 is *not* installed.